# Can't read innerHTML other properties are readable

Tags: javascript, jquery, properties, innerhtml, inspector

I am trying to identify a button by the displayed button text. In the Firefox developer tools I see the associated text in the `innerHTML` property - but I can't get access to it - it is empty.

```
$("#objbefDlg .dlg-buttons .dlg-button").each(function() {
    console.log("this ", this, " this.disabled ", this.disabled, " this.innerHTML ", this.innerHTML, " this.className ", this.className, " this.contentEditable ", this.contentEditable);       
});
```

The HTML-Code:

```
<div id="objbefDlg" class="dialog">
    <div class="dlg-main">
        <div id="objdlg-cont-left">
            ...
        </div>        
        <div id="objdlg-cont-right">
            ...
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="dlg-buttons">
        <button class="dlg-button"></button>
        <button class="dlg-button"></button>
        <button class="dlg-button"></button>
        <button class="dlg-button"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the other hand I get access to other properties without problems. Does anyone have a tip what else I could try?
I can't share the whole code, but here are some excerpts (elsewhere in the programme it works completely without problems).
Many thanks for your help
Lawinia

Edit: It seems that I'm not allowed to upload pictures, so I'll try to describe the outputs....

**Developer Tool Console Output:**

```
"this " <button class="dlg-button"> " this.disabled " false " this.innerHTML " "" " this.className " "dlg-button" " this.contentEditable " "inherit" 
"this " <button class="dlg-button"> " this.disabled " false " this.innerHTML " "" " this.className " "dlg-button" " this.contentEditable " "inherit" 
"this " <button class="dlg-button" disabled=""> " this.disabled " true " this.innerHTML " "" " this.className " "dlg-button" " this.contentEditable " "inherit" 
"this " <button class="dlg-button" disabled=""> " this.disabled " true " this.innerHTML " "" " this.className " "dlg-button" " this.contentEditable " "inherit"
```

**Developer Tool Properties:**

```
className: "dlg-button"    
contentEditable: "inherit"  
disabled: false  
innerHTML: "Interrompre"
```

Here i see the Text in innerHTML, but i can't read it.

Unfortunately, I often don't understand how accessing elements via javaScript and/or JQuery works or doesn't work. It is unclear to me why I cannot access innerHTML in this case. I hope that you can help me to bring some light into the darkness...

Comment: Looks like you want `innerText` not `innerHTML` as the object doesn't contain any HTML only text

Comment: Thanks for your responding. But i see the property innterHTML in firefox! I can't add an image to show you what I mean :-/ and innerText returns undefined too

Comment: Why you don't put IDs on your buttons? Using IDs is the best practice to identify HTML elements. Like so: <button id="my-bla-button" class="dlg-button">bla</button>. Then you can easily select that button by $("#my-bla-button")

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for your responding, but the problem is that the button text and order vary each time and are sent from the main application. Therefore, an ID would not help me, as it could be sometimes the first, sometimes the last button.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but if you're actually looping through buttons, rendering `this` should produce `[object HTMLButtonElement]` or `$(this)` might display `[object Object]`. It will be nice if we could see your HTML code

Comment: @Juan: I edited my post and added a part of the HTML Code. "this" produces <button class="dlg-button">. $(this): Object { 0: <button.dlg-button>, context: <button.dlg-button>, length: 1}

Comment: Well your JQuery code is correct. And if there was a text for your buttons like this `<button>myText</button>` then it would display with `innerHTML`

Comment: @Juan: Thanks for your help! I also do the filling via JavaScript. There is a Text in innerHTML - i see it in the DeveloperTools from Firefox as a Property with the correct text. But if i try to read it in my Code with this.innerHTML its empty. I am despairing - I see it, but I can't catch ist. I use this in other dialogs too, and it works fine - but here... *helpless*

Comment: If the button texts are fed via JQuery (Javascript) we need more code. Because without all the code it is difficult to be able to help you.

Comment: @Juan: I found the problem. The DeveloperTool dates up the information about an object after it has been printed in the console. I only fill the buttons at a later point in time (therefore an empty string came out during the concrete readout). By clicking on the object in the console, however, the updated state was displayed, as the object was updated in the background.
Many thanks for your help!